# How to apply CS_DROPSHADOW to a subclass of CDialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dropshadow, cdialog

I have a c++ class, `MyDialog`, deriving from `CDialog`, where I have removed the Windows frame and thereby the Windows generated shadow.

I would like to add the shadow again, without adding the frame. I have found there is a class style `CS_DROPSHADOW` that can be applied. But I cannot find how to apply it.

I have found a method `ModifyStyle` but it only modifies the `WS_...` styles, not the `CS_...` styles.

How do I apply the class style `CS_DROPSHADOW`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My colleague helped me to register a class with the class style like this:

```
    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    GetClassInfo(NULL, WC_DIALOG, &wndClass);
    wndClass.style |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyDialog");
    RegisterClass(&wndClass);
```

where `WC_DIALOG` is the class for the regular `CDialog`.

This class is then used in the resource file where my dialog is defined:

```
IDD_MYDIALOGEX 54, 22, 264, 95
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP
CLASS "MyDialog"
FONT 8, "Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    // Contents ...
END
```

This added a shadow, which is good. But not the aero shadow I was looking for though.
[image]

More answers welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to retain the frame style but respond to `WM_NCCALCSIZE` to have the client cover the entire window, effectively making the border zero width.

Comment: I tried manipulating the `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` in an `OnNcCalcSize` method. But if I inflate the rect (`lpncsp->rgrc`) the client either just gets smaller if decreased, or just gets a white frame when increased. The shadow is unchanged. How should I go about this?

Comment: @JOG, sorry that's the only idea I have for now. I've never tried to do this, but I know that trying to achieve something that Microsoft never conceived is always difficult. Sorry it didn't work out.